# What is the event for a TextView's text changed and shown?

Tags: android, textview, height

I have a method that rearranges the elements in the screen according to a TextView's height. I need to know what event to listen for whenever I change the text from the TextView AND it is shown, previous attempts to get the height of the TextView always show me the previous height (with dummy text) instead of the new height with the new text. What event do I need? Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a Google replacement. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Comment: Believe me, I have Googled a lot and still haven't found a solution. I tried onTextChanged but it still returns the old height instead of the new height with the new text. When debugging, I can see that the TextView hasn't changed in my emulator or my phone (even though the text property has changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed was the onLayoutChanged Event:

```
txtQuote.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            resizeSpacing();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add TextWatcher to the textview like below,

```
textView1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
    int count) {

    }

   @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
      int after) {
    }

   @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

});
```